# Odd drawing issue (black cells) in TStringGrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, tstringgrid

I encountered something really really really odd with TStringGrid (Delphi XE). I have seen that sometimes when I click the first line in my grid, it turns black (or shows scrambled canvas 'stolen' from other controls on form).
It happens ONLY in certain configurations, when the grid receives focus. Once you click another area in the grid everything looks ok until the focus is moved to another TStringGrid.

How to reproduce:

- put TWO string grids on a form
- set them as shown below (Update: I realized that goRowSelect and goEditing must be 'true')
- click the first cell in one grid -> nothing happens
- click the first cell in the second grid -> the first cell gets black (see screenshot)

The problem appears also in other circumstances (not necessary to have 2 grids on a form), but I  managed to reproduce it only when I have 2 grids.

```
object grid1: TStringGrid <------- same for Grid2
  Left = 2
  Top = 8
  Width = 422
  Height = 381
  BevelEdges = [beLeft, beTop]
  DefaultColWidth = 80
  DefaultRowHeight = 15
  DoubleBuffered = True
  FixedCols = 0
  Options = [goFixedVertLine, goFixedHorzLine, goVertLine, goHorzLine, goRangeSelect, goDrawFocusSelected, goColSizing, goEditing, goRowSelect, goFixedHotTrack]
  ParentDoubleBuffered = False
  TabOrder = 1
end
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: I can reproduce it with the given information.

Comment: Spent 2 hours tracking this down. I though it was a problem in my custom TStringGrid lib (especially the 'Draw' method).

Comment: @SertacAkyuz-which Delphi?

Comment: With XE. Does not seem to happen with XE2.

Comment: I could reproduce it partially with Delphi XE3 on Windows 7. In that cell I can see rendered themed header rectangle. And it happens only when I *focus* the control by clicking on the first column of the selected row.

Comment: Quick/dirty solution: Don't activate goRowSelect and goEditing at the same time (and remember it every time you use TStringGrid). Waiting for a better solution.

Comment: Options `goEditing` and `goRowSelect` are mutually exclusive. How would you edit the grid if you have selected whole row ?

Comment: @TLama If you want to have unique content for each cell in that row :D

Comment: @TLama-Yes, but the grid allows them both active at the same time. Which can lead to strange situations like this. Anyway, my 'bug' does not involve editing so, I don't know if these activating these two options together really causes the bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem with XE3 as well. After I have reset `ParentDoubleBuffered` to `True`, the problem is gone.

Generally speaking, when I see odd black rectangle in a control, I will first check the `ParentDoubleBuffered` settings. I saw you have enabled double buffering for the two grids.  Do you have any special reason to do that? If you intend to avoid flickering during resizing or cell update, there are [some techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712229/delphi-tstringgrid-flicker?rq=1) helpful.

Comment: Setting ParentDoubleBuffered will override DoubleBuffered (more exactly the Grid will use DoubleBuffered of the parent). So, it is pointless when you set ParentDoubleBuffered to true but you don't tell us what is the DoubleBuffered value of your parent. We can only guess that the DoubleBuffered of the parent is False (since something changed).

Comment: Good to hear you back after a two year delay ;-) I cannot remember the exact reason. I guess my point was the Form has actually set `DoubleBuffered` as `True`. There is no need to set everything double buffered.

Comment: "There is no need to set everything double buffered" - Is this a personal opinion or it can be explained? I thought there is a purpose for which Borland put that property there...

Comment: So, basically you mean this is a Delphi bug ('undocumented feature' :) ). And the problem can ONLY be fixed by disabling the DoubleBuffered ?